# formatting enum in gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

i need to display the name of enum in gridview
by data table returns its numeric value

i am using this for other columns

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="User Name" />
```

i need to use it for enum to display the string value of enum Gender

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Gender" HeaderText="Gender" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this solution

[Enum.GetName Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getname.aspx)

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Category">
<ItemTemplate>
<div>
<%# Enum.GetName(typeof(GlobalLibrary.Constants.Category),Convert.ToInt32(Eval("Category"))) %>
</div>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: i am trying something like this
<asp:BoundField DataField="<% # Enum.GetName(typeof(AR_Order.OrderType), Convert.ToInt32(Eval('OrderType'))) %>" HeaderText="Order Type">
but not wrking infact

Comment: Thanx man its wrking ... with templatefield
i was using boundfield,dnt knw y the same thing not wrking there

Answer (score 1):

It helped me :)
And then I found this simpler

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
  <ItemTemplate><%#(MyGenderEnum)Eval("Gender")%></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 1):

And if you prefer VB.NET:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" SortExpression="VisibilityStatus">
      <ItemTemplate>
          <%# [Enum].GetName(GetType(VisibilityStatusEnum), Eval("VisibilityStatus"))%>
      </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0):

This version worked for me in VB.NET:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Gender">
   <ItemTemplate><%# CType(Eval("Gender"), Gender).ToString() %></ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Iterestingly, it didn't work with DirectCast instead of CType, and was still displaying integers until I added ToString(). I also had to add namespace to my enum in my case.