# How to bind a generic list of enums to a GridView

Tags: asp.net, list, generics, gridview, enums

I am unable to bind a generic list of enums to a GridView, below are all of the details:

Error Message

> The data source for GridView with id 'GridView1' did not have any properties or attributes from which to generate columns.  Ensure that your data source has content.

ASPX Page

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="Amikids.Pages.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code Behind

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Amikids.Pages
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public enum Pet
        {
            Cat = 0,
            Dog = 1,
            Bird = 2
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            List<Pet> pets = new List<Pet>();
            pets.Add(Pet.Bird);
            pets.Add(Pet.Dog);

            GridView1.DataSource = pets;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3606700/formatting-enum-in-gridview ?

Comment: @DavidTansey - In the post you provided they are binding to an object that contains a property whose type is that of an enum. I am binding to a list of enum values. The important distinction is there is no datafield name to use. At first it may seem that you can use the name of the enum as the datafield name. However, just like if you were binding to a list of strings (ie List<string>) you could not use the word "string" as the datafield name. Hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not able to figure out how to directly bind a list of enum values to a GridView. As work-around I converted the list of enum values to a list of string values.

**Below - Code for Converting list of enum values to list of string values.**

```
public static List<string> ConvertListOfPetsToListOfStrings(List<Pet> pets)
{
    List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string>();
    foreach (Pet pet in pets)
    {
        listOfStrings.Add(pet.ToString());
    }
    return listOfStrings;
}
```

**Below - Code for binding to GridView**

```
        GridView1.DataSource = ConvertListOfPetsToListOfStrings(pets);
        GridView1.DataBind();
```

**Below - ASPX markup for binding to template field and setting a meaningfull HeaderText.**

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Type of Pet">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <%# Container.DataItem %>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```